# Are functions with variadic arguments required to call va_start?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Is it safe to exit a function with variadic parameters early, before it begins using `va_list`?

```
#include <cstdarg>

int func(const char * format, ...){
    if(format == NULL)
        return 0; // <-- exits before acknowledging variadic parameters; is this okay?
    va_list params;
    va_start(params, format);

    // func body

    va_end(params);
    return stuff;
}
```

Comment: Don't think there is any reason stopping you (for my knowledge).

Comment: Returning between `va_start` and `va_end` invokes undefined behavior. Returning before `va_start` or after `va_end` is okay.

Comment: Consider using parameter packs instead. It is a modern type-safe alternative. [Parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, this is legal. **No**, functions are not required to call `va_start`. From the C99 standard:

> If access to the varying arguments is desired, the called function
> shall declare an object ... having type va_list.

Notice two things here:

1. A `va_list` is a prerequisite to the `va_start` call.
2. A `va_list` is only necessary to have **if** access to the varying arguments is desired.

As such, also the `va_start` call is only necessary **if** access to the varying arguments is desired.